# How to view the contents of history object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser-history

The history object contains the URLs visited by the user (within a browser window). How do I view the visited URLs? I tried consoling the object and checked through all the fields, couldn't find the required data. history.back() will load the previous, but I just want to know the previous URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this.
It's made for security reasons.
However you can view the last one (page which you came from) by checking `document.referrer`.
See more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer)

Comment: Is there any other way to get the history? (I know I can manually stack up the URLs using location.href)

Comment: nope as far as i know, but look at solution below from @piterio

Comment: If it's a security reason why you are allowed to manipulate the history stack ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have some kind of solution saving the `document.referrer` using `localStorage` each time you need.