# Getting separate callbacks on browsers back and forward button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, browser-history, html5-history

I've a simple web-application, which consists of 3 simple pages

- a.html
- b.html
- c.html

```html
<!-- a.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="b.html">b.html</a>    
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
<!-- b.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <a href="a.html">a.html</a>    
            <br />
            <a href="c.html">c.html</a>  
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
<!-- c.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <a href="b.html">b.html</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

As can be seen from the above code, `a.html` has a link to `b.html`, `b.html` has a link to both `a.html` & `c.html` and finally, `c.html` has a link to `b.html`.

All of the pages will be hosted on the same domain, and I want a very simple thing. **All I want is to execute a callback whenever browser's back/forward button is pressed (specifically before navigating to the new page), and in the callback I want the page to which we'll be navigating. And I don't want to update the browser's history while achieving the above (I don't want to ruin the user's experience, updating browser-history will result in unexpected navigation for the user)**

### The solutions that I tried:

- `performance.navigation.type`
  [performance.navigation.type == 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53033622/2346131) can be used, but it doesn't distinguishes between back and forward button. So it's not of much use for me. **Is there any way to distinguish the back and forward button press here?**
- I don't want to distort `this.window.history` so that I can get a callback on  `onpopstate` (refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8738145/2346131)). Distorting the windows history means ruining the user-experience. **Can this be done without distorting the windows history?**
- I know that using `window.history` object, I can't find the URL to which the forward/back button will navigate to. ([This is because of security](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33368138/2346131)). But provided that all of my pages are on the same domain, can I somehow get the url to which fwd/back button will be taking me to. I'm mostly concerned about `b.html`. While I'm on `b.html` the forward/back button can take me to either `a.html` or `c.html`, how do I detect this before actual navigation happens, so that I can get a callback at this point and execute it.
- I tried using JQuery-Mobile but was stuck and posted it as a separate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57372803/jquery-mobiles-callback-on-navigate-not-executing). Though I'm not sure how JQuery Mobile achieves it and if it will distort the browser's history.
- I tried using React-routers, but they are more suited for a single-page-application, and so not much help from there also. Can this be done using any react-concepts?

Comment: `I want to execute a callback whenever browser's back/forward button is pressed` All you can do is run code in `beforeunload` but there's no way to know what caused that event to fire; the user may have typed in a new web address, or closed their browser. If there's a specific reason you want to know if the forward/back button was pressed you will need to re-engineer the page to work around this limitation.

Comment: Being able to hook into back/forward and know where it's going to go sounds like a **huge** security hole.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for the suggestion of `beforeunload`, but as you already told, it's not really of much use to me. Can you please explain what do you mean by "re-engineer the page to work around this limitation"?

Comment: The best way I could think of would be to change to use a Single Page Application. Then you can control exactly what content is shown and know which way the user is travelling through the page flow.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan fair-enough. But I'm afraid that this re-engineering will cost me a lot of effort, as the code that's written is already huge. Anyways thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @freedomn-m so do you mean that there is no way to do this? Should I stop investing my time finding a solution for this and revamp my application to be a single-page application as suggested by Rory?

Comment: It may be a lot of effort, but you don't really have much of an alternative.

Comment: I see you've already identified this as a security hole.  Well done for the research effort before asking. But you've essentially said: "I know I can't get url ... but can I get the url?".

Comment: I'm not sure you can even distinguish between back/forward before the action has occurred.

Comment: I would suggest reconsidering the need.  Seems to be fairly unique (otherwise there'd be a lot more questions about this) and I'm sure you've got a valid reason for this